# Chrome browser: Problems after upgrade with reading ip from etc/hosts of subdomains localhost

Tags: google-chrome, ip

I've a problem after I upgraded Chrome.
My Chrome's version is `43.0.2357.81 m`.
Chrome doesn't read ip from `/etc/hosts` for subdomains localhost (another `127.0.0.1`). 
I know Localhost name in Windows is reserved, but sudomain localhost is allowed  to another ip, set in `etc/hosts` (subdomain.localhost not reserved for `127.0.0.1`).

My etc/hosts:

```
...

192.168.0.166 pl.localhost

192.168.0.166 de.localhost
```

I'm using Windows 8.
Before uprgade everything worked fine.
In Firefox everything still works.

chrome:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxMgc.png

firefox:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bsnrg.png

I know, that changing the domain name in etc/hosts to another domain (eg. my-local) will work.

What a want to achieve is the subdomain ( eg. de.localhost ) to work as it DID work in all the previous versions of Chrome, and as it DOES work in FF, Opera, Safari etc.

I just don't get how the browser can change / ignore system's settings ( etc/host explicitly ).

Have you experienced this problem? Maybe do you know the solution to it?

I'd be very greatfull if you could help me out!

Answer (score 1):

I came across this same issue.

The workaround is to change from localhost to local or anything else.
You should change the hosts file entry to 192.168.0.166 pl.local
Also you should change the vhost file to ServerName to pl.local

Comment: Thanks you for your answer.

I know, that changing the domain name in etc/hosts to another domain (eg. my-local) will work.

What a want to achieve is the subdomain ( eg. de.localhost ) to work as it DID work in all the previous versions of Chrome, and as it DOES work in FF, Opera, Safari etc.

I just don't get how the browser can change / ignore system's settings ( etc/host explicitly ).

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem adding a "`.`" (dot) to localhost record in `/etc/hosts` file.
The new record is like this:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.
```